# Display the current post in browser as the first post in a loop (for a slideshow)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, slideshow

I have a custom post type - on a single page it displays all kinds of information for the post type. There are 10 posts altogether. Below the info I have a slideshow as part of a loop that displays the other posts. However this is always in alphabetical order.

I would like to be able to recognise the current single page and display it as the first entry in the loop. The loop uses a WP_Query so I need to figure out a way to have it sort this way.

How would I be able to do this? Does it involve a meta query?

EG: If current post is Post7, order by Post7, Post1, Post2, Post3 etc.

Comment: Simply `orderby` by `date` which is default in `WP_Query`

Comment: I don't mean the "latest" post, I mean the post that is being displayed in the browser - so for example if it shows "post7" in browser, the order for query is "post7, post1, post2, post3 etc."

Comment: That is info that should be **inside** your question

Comment: OK, it's there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most probably reuse the loop and run it twice. The first time to display the queried post and the second time to display the rest

```
// Get the current post id being viewed
$current_post_id = get_queried_object_id();

// Define your query and query arguments
$args = [
    // All your arguments
];
$q = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    // Run the loop for the first time to display the post equal to the queried one
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        if ( get_the_ID() == $current_post_id ) {
            // Display the post equal to the queried one
        }

    } // endwhile

    // Rewind the loop so that we can run it again
    $q->rewind_posts();

    // Run the loop for the second time to display all the other posts
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();

        if ( get_the_ID() != $current_post_id ) {
            // Display all the other posts skipping the queried one
        }

    } // endwhile

    // Clean after ourselves, good housekeeping
    wp_reset_postdata();
} // endif
```

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy ;-)